# Wilhelm II. und Ludwig XIV

Tags: colloquial, numbers, person-names

Ich habe gerade in Volker Kutschers »Der nasse Fisch«, oder vielleicht sollte ich *in Volker Kutschers »Nassem Fisch«* schreiben, den folgenden Satz gelesen :

> Der Mann erinnerte ein wenig an Wilhelm zwo.  Der markante Schnurrbart, der stechende Blick.

*Zwo* anstatt *zwei* kenne ich schon, aber ich hätte *Wilhelm den zweiten* erwartet.
Ist *Wilhelm zwo* einfach umgangssprachlich?
Könnte ich auch *Ludwig vierzehn* für Ludwig XIV. sagen?

Comment: Das ist eine sehr interessante Frage. Spontan dachte ich, das sei eine schnoddrige Berliner Verkürzung des korrekten "Wilhelm der zweite".  Das ist bei "Wilhem **zwo**" auch sicher der Fall, aber wie steht es mit "Wilhelm zwei"? Eine Internet-Suche liefert den offiziellen [Festvortrag „950 Jahre Hohenzollern“ auf der Hohenzollern-Stammburg, Hechingen, 29. Mai 2011](https://www.wolffsohn.de/cms/images/Snippets_pdf/michael%20wolffsohn%20950%20jahre%20hohenzollern.pdf) von Michael Wolffsohn. Dort findet man die Bezeichungen "Wilhelm eins", "Wilhelm zwei", "Friedrich Eins", "Friedrich Zwei"

Comment: und "Friedrich Wilhelm Vier". Könnte also bei Historikern so üblich sein. Siehe aber auch [hier](https://www.stadt-brueel.de/stadt/geschichte/till-dahlenburg---geschichte-vom-brueeler-land---teil2.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die korrekte Bezeichnung ist Wilhelm II., ausgesprochen "Wilhelm der zweite".
Das als "Wilhelm zwo" (oder sogar "Willem zwo") auszusprechen ist eine beliebte Anspielung auf die militärisch-knappe Ausdrucksweise, die in der Zeit verbreitet in Mode war und die er auch selber pflegte.
Das auch so zu schreiben wirkt dann schon leicht ironisch überspitzt.

Auch die Alternativform "zwo" für "zwei" ist vor allem im Militär- und Beamtendeutsch zuhause.

Für die Bezeichnung "Ludwig vierzehn" ist mir keine entsprechende Konnotation bekannt. Das empfinde ich persönlich schlicht als schlampige Ausdrucksweise.

Answer (score 8):

> ... aber ich hätte *Wilhelm den zweiten* erwartet. Ist *Wilhelm zwo* einfach umgangssprachlich?

Ja, *Wilhelm zwo* ist umgangssprachlich.

> Könnte ich auch *Ludwig vierzehn* für Ludwig XIV. sagen?

Genauso umgangssprachlich kann man auch *Ludwig vierzehn* für Ludwig XIV sagen.

Die korrekten Bezeichnungen,- die man z.B. in wissenschaftlichen Abhandlungen benutzen sollte -, sind wie Du bereits (fast korrekt<sup>1</sup>) erwähnt hast:

- *Wilhelm **der** zweite*
- *Ludwig der vierzehnte*

Also im verwendeten Zitat

> > Der Mann erinnerte ein wenig an **Wilhelm den zweiten**. Der markante Schnurrbart, der stechende Blick.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>Der Fakt, dass Du etwas erwartest, wirkt sich nicht auf die Flexion des Subjekts aus. Der Satz müsste korrekt

" ... aber ich hätte ***Wilhelm der zweite*** erwartet ..."

lauten.</sub>

Comment: Also ist "Wilhelm der zweite" gar nicht deklinierbar ?

Comment: @petitrien Doch, natürlich ist _Wilhelm der zweite_ deklinierbar, nur nicht sinnvolleweise im Kontext Deines Nebensatzes. Der bezieht sich auf Deine Erwartung, und die wäre eben _Wilhelm der zweite_ gewesen, und nicht _Wilhelm den zweiten_.

Comment: Versteh' ich jetzt, danke !

Comment: @petitrien _"oder vielleicht sollte ich in Volker Kutschers »Nassem Fisch« schreiben"_ Dasselbe Ding: _"oder vielleicht sollte ich in Volker Kutschers **»Der nasse Fisch«** schreiben"_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Was die Zwischenfrage in diesem konkreten Fall freilich unnötig macht.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Diskussion um die Deklination nicht ganz: das Zitat war "Der Mann erinnerte ein wenig an Wilhelm zwo." *Erinnern* verlangt den Akkusativ, also ist *ich hatte "Wilhelm den zweiten" erwartet* nicht falsch. Durch die fehlenden Anführungszeichen in der Frage wird es mehrdeutig :)

Comment: @Arsak Ja, Du hast recht, es ist ein wenig mehrdeutig. In dem Beispielsatz sollte natürlich die deklinierte Variante verwendet (erwartet) werden. Für die von mir angeführten Beispiele habe ich die Grundform verwendet.

Comment: @Arsak Ich habe meine Antwort ein wenig angepasst, um es klarer zu machen.